# Beanstalkd job switching to "ready" state

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, beanstalkd

I am running using Laravel with the Beanstalkd queue driver. I have some long running jobs and I am getting an issue where after about 60 seconds or so the job will move from reserved back to ready state. the job is still running and completes without an issue. The problem is that if another job is added it will not be run next, instead the previous job that has moved back to ready will run. if the job completes before  another is added it is not an issue though.

here is my code.

queue push:

```
  Queue::push('myApp\Processors\BuildQuick', $job);
```

job code:

```
public function fire($job, $data) {
         try {
         //some code here that calls another class to build an amazon ec2
         } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            \Logging::joblog($ex->getMessage(), "ERROR");
            $job->delete();
            return;
         }
      }

      $job->delete();
      \Logging::joblog("Job Completed Successfully", "INFO");
   }
```

update:
I have tested this with a sleep timer and it happens at exactly 1 minute every time. I know it is not throwing any exceptions and all my code does is sleep for 2 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found what was causing this issue!

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3480

this was added in laravel 4.1 I did not knwo this existed. you must change the default ttr in the queue config. Hope this helps others!

Comment: In short, the default 'ttr' (time to run) defaults to 60 seconds. If you have any jobs that can take longer than that, you'll need to add a `'ttr' => {number-of-seconds}` to the initial configuration. There does not yet appear to be an official, clean way to set the TTR on a per-job basis.